# Using a .txt file to populate a Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a Powershell script that queries Active Directory, by User ID, and outputs to a .csv file listing user attributes that I specify.

The script works flawlessly for a single user, but I would like to use a text file, with a list of users, to populate the script and create output for multiple users all at once.

Please advise.

This is my original script pulling the user list from a specific OU:
 import-module ActiveDirectory

```
$ADGroupParams=@{ 
'Server' = 'corp.xxxx.com' 
'Searchbase' = 'OU=Security Groups,DC=corp,DC=xxxx,DC=com' 
'Searchscope'= 'Subtree' 
'Filter' = '*' 
'Properties' = '*' 
} 
 $SelectParams=@{ 
'Property' = 'cn', 'managedBy', 'info', 'sAMAccountName', 'created' 
} 
 get-aduser @ADGroupParams | select-object @SelectParams  | export-csv "C:\Scripts\Users_By_OU.csv"
```

Comment: You need to show your script to get help

Comment: Use `Get-Content` and then construct a loop from the resulting data. There are plenty of articles on the web about how to do this. Have a go and then come back.

Comment: I took a stab at an answer but without the contents of your existing script and what your `users.txt` will look like, it's impossible to know exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text file is a `txt` file with one username per line:

```
# Put all ADUser properties you want dumped to the CSV in an array
$adUserProperties = @(
  'one',
  'attribute',
  'per',
  'index'
)

# Read the users from the file, get the ADUser object for each one,
# selecting the properties you want dumped to the CSV, and export the
# returned information to a CSV file.
Get-Content \path\to\users.txt | Foreach-Object {
  Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($_)'" -Properties $adUserProperties
} | Select-Object -Properties $adUserProperties | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation users.csv
```